# sharepoint 2010 Retention Policy not working?

Tags: list

I have created one simple document library and want to enable a retention policy for that, for this thing I have created one document library and have navigated to following steps:

1) Document Library Settings --> Information management policy settings

2) selected the "Document" as Content Type.

3) Checked on "Enable Retention",

4) Click on "Add a retention stage"

5) here I defined that "Date Created" + 1 " Day", should need to move in recycle bin.

According to above defined policy the documents which are created date spent on more than one day should automatically move to recycle bin, but it is not moving or doing anything, does anything help me in this context? That does i need to enable from Cetral Administration or enable any feature or need to do something more to allow that policy to work fine?? I have multiple documents in the library that have a created date over the 3 days. How often is the retention policy run? daily? weekly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following things must happen after above policy was set and before your documents are moved to recycle Bin:

1. Information management policy completed successfully
2. Expiration Policy completed successfully.

**Both jobs are by default scheduled to run on a "Weekly" basis**.

To Quickly test whether it is working (or any change in policy you made), perform following actions for above jobs in order in which mentioned above:

1. Go to Central Admin > Monitoring > Review Job Definition. Filter the list by your Web Application
2. Locate the job and select Run Now
3. Monitor the job history and make sure the job was run successfully on your web application

You might have figured out now, first jobs calculates the expiry date for the documents based on the policy. The second job actually deletes the documents marked to be deleted by the first job.

Comment: I can't comment on your answer Ashish, but I'm having the same issue in SharePoint Online. However, I can't go look at my job definitions and force it to run. Can this be done through powershell for SP Online?

Comment: For anyone that stumbles upon this, in SPOnline you could possibly have to wait for a week for the SPOnline servers to run this timer job before your policies begin to run.

Comment: @Brandon yes, you need patience here.