# retention doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-server, expiration, irm, retention

I'm trying to use retention on a document library. I configured a list and defined a retention policy to move the file to recycle bin after a day.

When I check in compliance details, I see that it should be moved to recycle bin but the expiration date is 2 days passed.

I go to Central Admin > Monitoring > Review Job Definition and changed to run every 5 minutes for testing without success.

Secondly, I can't find "Expiration policy" when I go in central admin > security and configure information management policy.

When I run in powershell console:

```
PS C:\Users\SharePoint> Get-SPTimerJob  | Format-Table -Property DisplayName,LastRunTime,Status
```

I see:

```
Expiration policy          1/01/0001 00:00:00                            Online
```

Do I forget something?

Comment: Similar question has been answered in our forum earlier. Please check the following link [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25412/sharepoint-2010-retention-policy-not-working)

Comment: i saw this post but didn't resolve my issue. where can i see 3.Monitor the job history

Comment: Go to Central Admin > Monitoring > Job Status > History (Left Side navigation )

Comment: i see Information management policy succeed but i don't see "Expiration policy"

Comment: So may be that is the problem. Run it manually

Comment: and how can i do this? thanks for your help

Comment: Click on that job a page will open, you will see a button "Run Now". Click it

Comment: Information management policy succed but when i look in google they talke about another job called "Expiration policy" and i don't see it

Comment: check this link http://blogs.technet.com/b/manjesh/archive/2010/01/10/how-to-configure-document-expiration-policy.aspx

Comment: it's there my issue, in step A point 2, i don't see expiration. i have retention, labels, barcodes, auditing